# inet_pton is not a valid Socket macro

Tags: perl, sockets, snmp, ipv6

I am getting below error with perl package 5.10.

"inet_pton is not a valid Socket macro"

```
if (Socket::inet_pton (AF_INET6,$self->{'ip'}) )
  {

    $log->print("we hit here and ip=$self->{'ip'}");
     $self->{'session'} = Net::SNMP->session(-hostname =>   $self->{'ip'},
                                             -community =>  $self->{'community'},
                                             -port =>       $self->{'port'},
                                             -version =>    'snmpv2c');
  }
```

Can you pls let me know the root cause ?

Comment: @Martin - No this is Linux machine

Answer (score 0):

Socket uses an autoloader. That's the message it produces when you try to call a sub that doesn't exist.

```
$ perl -MSocket -wE'my $x = Socket::some_name()'
some_name is not a valid Socket macro at -e line 1
```

In other words, the error message is synonymous with

```
Undefined subroutine &Socket::inet_pton called
```

You must have a version of Socket that predates the addition of the module's support for `inet_pton`. Therefore, the fix is simply to upgrade that module.

Comment: thanks ! do you know any alternative utility for IPv6 on same perl version ?

Comment: The newer Socket should work fine with your existing version of Perl

Comment: whether Net::IP::ip_expand_address will do same work as that of inet_pton?

Answer (score -1):

Your Perl is too old. As far as I can tell, `inet_pton` support wasn't added until 5.12. Installing a newer version of `Socket` from CPAN may help, but I wouldn't bet on it. Perl 5.10 came out in 2007, and the IPv6 support back then was much worse than it is today.

Comment: The version of Perl has nothing to do with this, nor does the state of things back in 2007.

Comment: thanks ! do you know any alternative utility for inet_pton(IPv6) on same perl version